# Create a blank page without blocking text

Tags: pdftex

In Latex (pdftext), I wanted to create a blank page which cut the text smartly, so that the text fill the page perfectly. The blank page can contains an image, but can be empty.

More precisely, for example, if the sentence at the bottom of a page is "*Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet*", and that the "*amet*" word is in the next page, the software put the blank page after "*sit*".
Indeed, I cannot know before compiling where is the ceisure! So I cannot know where to put the `\newpage` instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}[p]
\vspace*{\textheight}
\end{figure}
```

will generate a blank page as soon as possible

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
a
\begin{figure}[p]
\vspace*{\textheight}
\end{figure}
b
\end{document}
```

produces "a b" with a blank page following

[image]